# How to customise a CNN layers with TensorFlow 2, Feed new inputs at Dense Layers of CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I want a model like so

[image: CNN Architecutre extracting from frequencies]

As you can see based on the image, I am trying to input statistical features along with the features extracted from the convolution layer into the dense layer.

In Tensorflow 2 there is a `Sequential()` function which allows me to do replicate the architecture but I'm not sure how to add new information together with the extracted features into the dense layer.

How can this be accomplished?

Current code below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(196,  16, activation='relu', input_shape=(segment_size,num_input_channels)))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(MaxPool1D(4))
model.add(Flatten())
// I want to add statisfical features here such as mean, max , min 

model.add(Dense(1024, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Can you add your current code here?

Comment: No problems, happy to help =)